# Building C++ Static Array Across Multiple Source Files

Tags: c++

I have a system that looks something like this:

**Master.h**

```
extern const Activators[2];
```

**Master.cpp**

```
#include <TypeOne.h>
#include <TypeTwo.h>
const Activators[2] = { &TypeOne::Create, &TypeTwo::Create };
```

Where you can imagine TypeOne and TypeTwo are classes with a static Create method that returns a new instance.

I'm looking for a way to decompose this system such that there doesn't need to be a single file that creates a link-time dependency on all of the types.

I'd like to be able to link together a unit test with just TypeOne's object file and a version of the static Activators array that is only filled with the function pointer to TypeOne's Create method.

Is there a way in C++ to create a statically-defined array and then fill individual slots in that array across compilation units? Ideally I'd be able to have something like this:

**Master.cpp**

```
const Activators[2];
```

**TypeOne.cpp**

```
Activators[0] = &TypeOne::Create;
```

**TypeTwo.cpp**

```
Activators[1] = &TypeTwo::Create;
```

Comment: How is `Activator` defined?

Comment: Let Type*.cpp include Master.h and set each field.

Comment: Does Activators need to be `const`?

Comment: Activators doesn't need to be const.

Comment: And for simplicity, assume Activator is defined as typedef void* (*Activator)(void); where it returns a void* to the created object.

Comment: @Andrew: This code is missing a detail, what are the types of the elements inside the `Activators` array?  Unless the elements are called `Activators` and the array is _also_ named `Activators`, which is a terrible, terrible idea.

Comment: Also, how portable does the code have to be? All of the answers here are _technically_ undefined behavior, but in practice tend to be almost completely safe.

Comment: It seem to me like what you may need is a factory pattern. E.g. in the main program, you could have a static map, which is declared extern in all other modules. When modules load, they insert themselves using their name into the map. This is a portable way to achieve more less what you want.

Comment: Is `Activators` a typedef for a funtion pointer? or what

Comment: Expanding on the facotry idea: Protect it from init-order issues by having it live in a function. You have some code in TypeOne's unit call `get_factory().register(some_key, &TypeOne::Create);` , where `some_key` could be a common `enum`, or even a string.  Then when it is time to create an object, the factory can gracefully deny requests for types that have not registered yet.

Answer (score 1):

The way C++ initializes globals is *really* weird, and technically the other answers thus far have undefined behavior, though will probably work on your machine/compiler anyway.  Basically, the problem is that when the program starts, the implementation is only required to initialize the globals in main.cpp and it's headers.  When your code calls a function that's defined in another cpp/header combo (translation unit), *only then* is C++ required to initialize the globals *in that one translation unit*.

The easiest (safe) workaround in *your particular case*, is to simply do the initialization in the header.  If a file has `include "TypeOne.h"`, it will initialize `Activators[0]` itself.  To be portable, it's important that the translation unit (cpp file) that contains `int main()` also includes the headers for all of these that you need to use.  Otherwise, you aren't strictly guaranteed that they'll be initialized before `main` begins.

in TypeOne.h

```
#include "master.h"

class TypeOne { 
    static std::unique_ptr<TypeOne> Create();
    //stuff
};
static const auto TypeOneInitialized = Activators[0] = &TypeOne::Create;
```

If you have a cpp who shouldn't depend on TypeTwo, simply don't include  it's header.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Although you need to be very careful.

#### `TypeOne.cpp`

```
namespace {
    class BeforeMain {
        BeforeMain() {
            Activators[0] = &TypeOne::Create;
        }
    };

    BeforeMain obj;
}
```

#### `TypeTwo.cpp`

```
namespace {
    class BeforeMain {
        BeforeMain() {
            Activators[1] = &TypeTwo::Create;
        }
    };

    BeforeMain obj;
}
```

Then, other than this, just don't access the array until `main()` is called.

Personally though, I'd rather see `Activators` be a `std::vector<T>`, and then have each `BeforeMain` use `std::vector<T>::push_back()`.

Comment: _Technically_ this isn't portable, the globals are not guaranteed to be initialized until a function in `main.cpp`'s TU tries to call a function in each of those TUs.  (This applies to all answers thus far)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Really? I didn't know that.. For anyone else reading, [here's some more information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271248/c-when-and-how-are-c-global-static-constructors-called).

Comment: @MooingDuck, so have `main()` open up with `TU1dummy_func(); TU2dummy_func();`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Activators` are a polymorhpic (where `Type1` and `Type2` both derive from `Activators`) type, I would approach the problem like this.

## Activators.h

`std::vector<std::unique_ptr>>& activators();`

## Activators.cpp

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr>>& activators()
{
   static std::vector<std::unique_ptr>> the_array(2);
   return the_array;
}
```

Then in individual compilation units you can assign whatever you want:

## Type1.cpp

```
#include "Activators.h"

struct setup_activator_type_1
{
    setup_activator_type_1()
    {
       activators()[0].reset(new Type1);
    }
};

static setup_activator_type_1 type1_static_initializer;
```

Comment: Correct on both comments.  Fixed.

Comment: Ahh this looks close to exactly what I'd like to do. Is it legal C++ to do those assignments outside of a function?

Comment: The assignments need to happen in a function.  I've updated the answer to give an idea on one way this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would provide a functional interface to add `Activators` and use it from **TypeOne.cpp** and **TypeTwo.cpp**.

In **Activators.h**:

```
void addActivator(Activator activator);
```

In **Activators.cpp**:

```
static std::vector<Activator> activators{};

void addActivator(Activator activator)
{
   activators.push_back(activator);
}
```

In **TypeOne.cpp**:

```
struct Initializer
{
   Initializer()
   {
      addActivator(&TypeOne::Create);
   }
};

static Initializer initializer;
```

In **TypeTwo.cpp**:

```
struct Initializer
{
   Initializer()
   {
      addActivator(&TypeTwo::Create);
   }
};

static Initializer initializer;
```