# Why are we not allowed to have assignment statements in the file scope in C?

Tags: c, global-variables

Why are we only allowed to declare and define variables in global section?Why not include assignment in global section?
Example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a;
a=5;//Valid because its similar to int a=5; Therefore a initialiser to a Tentative definition
a=8;//Invalid because We can have only one initialiser for a tentative definition
void main(){
 ...
}
```

**Why do we need this? What would be the consequences if we were allowed to have more than one initializer to a tentative definition**

My next question is why only constant initializer elements are allowed?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int i=5;
int j=i+5;//[Error] initializer element is not constant
void main(){
 ...
}
```

**Similarly what would be the consequences we face if this rule was not present?**

Please note my question is not exactly why this happens? I'm trying to figure why these restrictions were given in the first place.

Comment: The global area (the space between the functions) doesn't get executed. Only functions get executed. The global area between the functions is used to tell the compiler what memory to set aside for what purposes.

Comment: It's not just assignments. No statement is allowed in file scope, only declarations.

Comment: What would that even mean? When would that code be executed, and in what order?

Comment: @delnan I will change it with better syntax then

Comment: Which language are you asking about? The second example is perfectly cromulent C++; it's only C that requires constant initialisers for globals.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The problem is related to C and thanks for letting me know it works in C++ and making me search for the word "cromulent".

Answer (score 3):

For both questions the answer is the same, in file scope there is no execution of statements or evaluation of expressions, all is done at compile time.

Other languages (C++ is an example) have a model for dynamic initialization at program startup. This is a complicated issue, e.g because initializers that come from different compilation units don't have a natural ordering among them, but might implicitly depend on each other. SO is an excelent source of information for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271248/c-when-and-how-are-c-global-static-constructors-called), too.

C tries to stay simple, simple to use for a programmer and simple to implement for compiler builders.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the quick reply. I would really appreciate it if you could explain a little on that second paragraph or point me to some article, or anything explaining that. It seems to be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

We are not allowed to use assignment in file scope because program execution starts from main. Compiler creates _start function which is executed first and then jump to main is made from there. When main returns, control goes back to _start which is having proper exit procedure to terminate program. So anything which is written outside the functions is only meant for the initializations which will be done compile time

Initialization is different from declaration and assignment. When we initialize variable compiler will make such arrangement that when program execution starts, its value will be what we have initialized. But when we declare a variable, it will be having default initial value specified by its scope. Assignment is done at runtime and not at compile time

Comment: +1 for the Excellent information. Glad you helped me learn something informative.