# Global Section Rules In C

Tags: c, global

I have some questions about global section rules in C, I'll state my question in cases.

**Case 1**: Why is this not allowed, says redefinition.

```
int a = 4;
a = 5;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

**Case 2**: Why is this not allowed.

```
int a;
int b;
a = b;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

**Case 3**: Why is this not allowed.

```
int a;
a = 4;
a = 5;//if this is removed, it works fine

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

**Case 4**: Why is this allowed, but test is not printed.

```
int test(void)
{printf("test");}
test();
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note that a C program  start from the `main` function so any code that is not called from the `main` directly or indirectly will not be executed.

Comment: You can't have assignments outside of functions, only declarations and definitions.

Comment: @AbdelfettahBesbes I understand that, however typing printf("test"); instead of the function call gives an error, while the function call does not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195619/why-are-we-not-allowed-to-have-assignment-statements-in-the-file-scope-in-c

Comment: `test();` is outside of `main()` so it is not executable (or compilable) code. Move it into `main()`.

Comment: Most programming languages won't let you write code outside of a function.

Comment: @AndréSanson — but there are exceptions, such as shell, Perl, Python, …

Answer (score 3):

**case 1:**

- because you're doing assignment outside of function.

**case 2:**

- because you're doing assignment outside of function.

**case 3:**

- because you're doing assignment outside of function.
- The first assignment is considered as initialization that's why it's fine.

**case 4:**

- because you're just declaring `test()` function again with different signature if the default is not `int`.
- and, You're not calling `test()` from the `main` function.

```
int test(void)
{
  printf("test");
  return 0; // it can cause a warning if missing
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In case 4 he is not calling test at all! He is declaring the function test (right after it definition).

Answer (score 2):

The "global" section is actually compiled into a segment in the binary executable that is then loaded into memory when you program runs.

The exact details of how it works depend on the specific OS you build for, but basically, the only thing that you can do in the global section is declare or define initialized or uninitialized variables.

In your **case 1** you fist define an initialized global variable `a`, but then you try to assign a *new* value to it.

This is actual code that needs to run after the program is loaded, so it has to be inside a function!

Your **case 2** is almost same as one: you define 2 uninitialized global variables, but then you add code to manipulate them.
This code has to be inside a function!

**case 3** is more interesting:
If you try to compile it, you should get warnings like this:

```
warning: data definition has no type or storage class a = 4;
warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘a’ [-Wimplicit-int]
```

The compiler thinks you are defining a variable without a type, but with a value, so it assigns a default type of `int` to it.

Notice this will also work:

```
int a;
int a = 4;
```

And will remove the warnings.

The compiler will treat the first line as declaration only (an intent to have a variable named `a`, but not the actual variable) and the second line will be the actual definition, creating the variable and initializing it with value 4.

Keep in mind, that in C, initializing a variable, and assigning value to it are two slightly different things with different rules.

Finally **case 4** is very simple:
"test" is not printed because you never call the function `test()`.

```
int test(void)
{printf("test");}
test();
```

This code is same as this code:

```
int test(void);

int main() {
    ...
}

int test(void)
{
    printf("test");
}
```

What you did with the last line in you example is simply declare a function.
You told the compiler that somewhere in your code exists a function named `test` that expects no parameters and returns an integer value. (if you do not specify return type for function C default to `int`!)

Anything you write int the global scope the compiler will try to interpret as a declaration (you tell the compiler something exists) or a definition (you tell the compiler what something is).

If it can not interpret your statement this way you will get a compilation error.

You can not run code from global scope in C.