# How to get a list of methods from a particular gRPC service in C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto3, grpc-c++

I have a proto3 gRPC service with these methods:

```
syntax = "proto3";

Service MyService
{
    rpc Foo (FooRequest) returns (FooResponse) {}
    rpc Bar (BarRequest) returns (BarResponse) {}
   // etc.
}
```

I would like to access these methods dynamically in my C++ application, e.g.

```
google::protobuf::ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor;
google::protobuf::MethodDescriptor* myMethod = serviceDescriptor.FindMethodByName("Foo");
```

It is trivial to get a message descriptor using `google::protobuf::MessageDescriptor = myMessage.GetDescriptor();`, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent method for a service.

**How do I get a `ServiceDescriptor` for a Service in C++?**

My instinct is that getting the `ServiceDescriptor` is required to get the list of gRPC methods, but if there is another way of accomplishing this I would also be interested.

Comment: Yes `ServiceDescriptor` gets you `MethodDescriptors` but you'll need to start from the root `FileDescriptor`(?). I've not done this in Java but Golang('s new Protobuf) SDK has a useful `protoreflect` module that I've used to do similar. See: https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect#ServiceDescriptor. There appears to be a Java equivalent: https://javadoc.io/static/io.grpc/grpc-services/1.15.1/io/grpc/protobuf/services/ProtoReflectionService.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are statically linking your Protobuf generated source file (e.g. MyService.pb.cc) you should be able to get a ServiceDescriptor from the `generated_pool` DescriptorPool.

```
#include <google/protobuf/descriptor.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  const google::protobuf::DescriptorPool* p = google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::generated_pool();
  const google::protobuf::ServiceDescriptor* serviceDescriptor = p->FindServiceByName("MyService");
  const google::protobuf::MethodDescriptor* method = serviceDescriptor->FindMethodByName("Foo");
}
```

See also [Protobuf message object creation by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960871/protobuf-message-object-creation-by-name)

To get a full list of methods of a service, you can use `int ServiceDescriptor::method_count() const` and `const MethodDescriptor* ServiceDescriptor::method(int index) const`.

Comment: This seems to be working fine for `FindMessageTypeByName` but I can't make it work for services, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

By using the trick of adding an Empty message before your service, you could get a [`FileDescriptor`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor?hl=en#FileDescriptor) and then access the services. This is described in [this part](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor?hl=en#FileDescriptor) of the doc.

```
message MyMessage {}

service MyService {
    rpc MyMethod(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}
```

and then in C++ you would do:

```
MyMessage msg;
const FileDescriptor *desc = msg.descriptor()->file();

for (int i = 0; i < desc->service_count(); ++i) {
   for (int j = 0; j < desc->service(i)->method_count(); ++j) {
      std::cout << desc->service(i)->method(j)->name() << std::endl;
   }
}
```

However, **this is obviously a trick and shouldn't be used in production**. I'm still searching for a better answer and I'll update this answer over time.

### Update

Another solution you might have is to define a [`DescriptorPool`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor?hl=en#DescriptorPool). This is a more advanced solution but its apparently the recommended one.

```
auto st = new DiskSourceTree;

// add path(s) where the proto files are
st->MapPath("", "PATH_FOR_YOUR_PROTOS");
st->MapPath("", "PROTOBUF_INSTALL_PATH/include/"); // needed if you want to use Well Known Types

auto db = new SourceTreeDescriptorDatabase(st);
auto dp = std::make_unique<DescriptorPool>(new DescriptorPool(db));
FileDescriptor desc = dp->FindFileByName("your_file.proto");
```

After that you will be able to use `desc` in the same way as described in the previous version of my answer (the for loops part).

`PATH_FOR_YOUR_PROTOS` might be a directory or a file and the `PROTOBUF_INSTALL_PATH` is generally where you installed gRPC. This `PROTOBUF_INSTALL_PATH` should have an include directory in which you can find a `google`.

I highly recommend checking [the importer.h documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.compiler.importer?hl=en) and [the descriptor.h one](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor?hl=en)