# How to return google protocol messages from factory as unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, abstract-class, smart-pointers

I am still trying to understand how to use the Google Protocol Buffers library so I hope you will excuse my ingorance if this is off topic.

I want to wrap the Google Proto Factory such that the message types are placed in unique_ptrs so I don't have to worry about the memory management.

This is what I have:

```
  ProtoBufFactory::ProtoBufFactory() {
      Anon::Protocol_descriptor();
      Auth::Protocol_descriptor();
      m_factory = ::google::protobuf::MessageFactory::generated_factory();
    }

    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960871/protobuf-message-object-creation-by-name
    std::unique_ptr<::google::protobuf::Message> ProtoBufFactory::create(const ::google::protobuf::Descriptor * msg_descriptor) {
      const ::google::protobuf::Message * prototype_msg = m_factory->GetPrototype( msg_descriptor );

      if (prototype_msg == nullptr) {
        EXCEPT(1, "Cannot create prototype message from message descriptor");
      }

      ::google::protobuf::Message * mutable_msg = prototype_msg->New();

      if (mutable_msg == NULL) {
        EXCEPT(1, "Failed in prototype_msg->New(); to create mutable message");
      }

      return std::make_unique<::google::protobuf::Message>(mutable_msg);
    }
```

I'm getting an error indicating that I cannot do this because I am operating on an abstract type.

```
error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘google::protobuf::Message’
  857 |     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
/include/google/protobuf/message.h:235:23: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘google::protobuf::Message’:
  235 | class PROTOBUF_EXPORT Message : public MessageLite {
      |                       ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/message.h:244:12: note:      ‘virtual google::protobuf::Message* google::protobuf::Message::New() const’
  244 |   Message* New() const override = 0;
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/message_lite.h:465:15: note:         ‘virtual int google::protobuf::MessageLite::GetCachedSize() const’
  465 |   virtual int GetCachedSize() const = 0;
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/message.h:367:20: note:      ‘virtual google::protobuf::Metadata google::protobuf::Message::GetMetadata() const’
  367 |   virtual Metadata GetMetadata() const = 0;
```

I am confused by this error message. There is a reddit post where a similar error was reported unrelated to google protobuf: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/goa2he/stdunique_ptr_stdmake_unique_and_abstract_classes/

that seems to be because child classes were missing implementations of the abstract class. I thought it might be a linker problem but from what I can tell I'm linking the C++ protobuf generated files.

I'm not quite sure how best to proceed with this or even if unique_ptrs are all that beneficial in this circumstance.

I was hoping that there was an easy way to create a unique_ptr to the Google protocol buffer messages so I do not have to worry about explicitly deleting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::make_unique` is misnamed.  It should be `std::emplace_unique_ptr`.

It both creates the object *and* allocates space for it *and* stores it in a smart pointer.

As you already have an object *and* space for it, you don't use `make_unique`:

```
return std::unique_ptr<::google::protobuf::Message>(mutable_msg);
```

but instead just make a `unique_ptr` wrapping the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You have constructed the `mutable_msg` above the `return`, you don't need `std::make_unique()` that attempts to create another object. Just return the existing pointer, let the compiler return  `std::unique_ptr<::google::protobuf::Message>` constructed from the pointer:

```
return mutable_msg;
```

---

`if (prototype_msg == nullptr)` looks nice.
`if (mutable_msg == NULL)` does not look nice.